# Best Way of Handling Value Types That Require an Auto value?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to go about supporting an "auto" value for value types?

Let's say I wanted to float a texture 5 units off the right side of the screen. I wanted the end-developer to set the value like so:

```
mytexture.Margin.Right = 5;
mytexture.Margin.Left = int.Auto;
```

Internally, my 'layout manager' would need to know the end result of the positioning, but maintain that it is an automatic property for future comparisons and use.

So far I have been implementing this via a new value type that handles every possible conversion under the sun but has an extra field to declare whether or not it represents an automatically set value or not.

Is this correct? Or is there a better way of handling this? My code currently ends up as:

```
mytexture.Margin.Right = 5;
mytexture.Margin.Left = Size.Auto;
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your type? Structures can have constructors, so you can set defaults there.

Comment: @Oded - I do exactly that. And I use implicit casting to support various conversion scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also model this after the GridLength type available in WPF.

They basically made a struct, with a double value (amongst other things).  They added implicit cast operators so it is easy to use from code:

```
RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
row.Height = 25; //Same as new GridLength(25);
row.Height = GridLength.Auto;
```

I'm sure they specifically check for the static member, GridLength.Auto underneath the hood to do the work.

[MSDN for GridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx)

Comment: Actually GridLength does not provide implicit (or explicit) conversions so your code doesn't compile. However, the pattern is useful and one could provide them on their own type.

Comment: Well, I think there is a similar struct for the Width and Height of ASP.Net WebForms controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx  It actually has the implicit operators I was thinking of.

Comment: This is what I have been doing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very *similar* to `Nullable<T>`, in terms of having "any value, but also a flag saying whether or not a value is set". You could *either* use `Nullable<T>` directly, or if you felt that was a little bit of an abuse of the type, you could write your own similar type, e.g. `Defaultable<T>`.

Comment: I was thinking of discriminated unions when reading the question, but Nullable's a much better match for C#...

Comment: Interesting solution, though I am not sure the lack of difference between the various types (Defaultable<int> representing a size and Defaultable<int> representing a position) wouldn't be a problem for code readability.

Comment: @Krisc: You could always create your own `Size` and `Position` structs as well.